# How to speed up TCP initial connection time in standalone matlab program

Tags: matlab, tcp

I have been trying to make this standalone matlab code that uses the TCP networking commands given by matlab.  When I debug the code in the matlab enviornment it connects right away, but when I run it as a stand alone it takes forever to connect or does not connect at all.  It basically becomes very unreliable during the connection set up.  Once the connection is set up data is sent and received quickly without issue.  Does anyone know why this is happening or have a way to fix this?

Comment: Could be an issue with your firewall.

Comment: I have tried that in the past and it did not fix the problem.  It looks like it has trouble grabbing a port.

Comment: If you're on windows os and using recent release of Matlab you may want to try out writing in Matlab `client = System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient('www.mathworks.com', 80)` just to see if using directly .NET's `TcpClient` has same issue as Matlab's `TcpClient` or not in deployed mode. NB: I'm not saying to use .NET's `TcpClient` any later, it's just a test to see if it's related to Matlab's implementation.